# WooCommerce - Variable Attributes

Tags: attributes, woocommerce

I am looking into make a product that has what I would describe as variable attributes.

For example, if I am selling a t-shirt - the large size would be in blue, but the medium size would be in red.

Any hints/breadcrumbs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just specify the color of the shirt in the product variations? In other words, your variations could just be listed on the product details page as:

- Large Shirt (Blue)
- Medium Shirt (Red)

Answer (score 0):

Try going under the actual product itself (from the menu on the right click products) then click the product you wish to edit (the t shirt for instance)

Below that you should see a list of tabs under Product Data

Variations should be one of them. You can define them to your hearts content.

Hope that helps!